# How can I lock an async function so it waits for the first call to finish before running again

Tags: ios, swift

I dont want the same async function running multiple times in a row.  I want the function to wait until the first call of the function to finish before having the ability to run again

I've tried unwiring the event and then wiring it back up but that doesn't seem to stop the function from being called multiple times

code:

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
 myScrollView.delegate = nil
 myAsync()
 myScrollView.delegate = self
}
```

I've also tried setting the delegates to nil and self inside of the function but that didn't work either

Comment: Rework it to use a non-concurrent `NSOperationQueue` so only one task at a time runs.

Comment: That was my first thought, too. But if I understand the question correctly the OP wants to prevent that the async function can be called again and again while it is still being executed. When you use an `NSOperationQueue` and keep adding an `NSOperation` for every call to the async function you will end up with a lot of sequential operations in the queue that will take a long time to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a Bool property `running` and set it to `true` when the async function is called. When the async function finishes set it back to `false`. Then you only call the async function when `running == false`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !running {
        running = true
        myAsync()
    }
}

func myAsync() {
    // do your async stuff
    running = false // this has to be done on the main thread after the async stuff has finished
}
```